# npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons command it throwing an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to link react native with react native vector icons as shown in the docs https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/3.4.2/getting_started#install-react-native-vector-icons but it's throwing an error in my terminal of:

error Unrecognized command "link".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.

I am using a Git Bash terminal, I have tried using a PowerShell terminal and Command Prompt and nothing works. I have tried to google the answer and I see close but not the same problem. Can anyone please help me

Comment: Check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080373/7017860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/releases/tag/v8.0.0

It seems like `link` and `unlink` commands have been removed from react-native cli. You can rely on autolinking to complete your library installtion and react-native-vector-icons does support autolinking.

Please follow installation instructions directly from library [README.md](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/README.md) as documentation in other places might be outdated.

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080373/7017860

Comment: Thank you too Uzef Shaikh