# Unrecognized command "link" when linking fonts in react native

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

Trying to link custom fonts in a react native project, when using npx react-native link I get an error saying Unrecognized command "link"

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: This question has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831181/4781064

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Due to autolinking, link and unlink commands have been removed in [React Native 0.69](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/06/21/version-069#breaking-changes).

So, please try this:

```
npx react-native-asset
```

Comment: Does this work for libraries as well as assets?

Comment: @conor909 I have used it for a few libraries and not encountered any problems yet. But i'm not sure anyway.

Comment: LOL can't find module react-native.config.js

Comment: @Yiping you can create it manually (see the other answer)

Answer (score 41):

manual linking has been removed from react-native 0.69 in favour of autolinking feature so now you have link your assets in native module or else you can use
[react-native-asset](https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-native-asset)

remaining steps are same as before crate a file in root directory of project

react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/'],
};
```

after installing react-native-asset run below command

```
yarn react-native-asset or npx react-native-asset
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual setup for icons & try these steps

1.add this line android/app/build.gradle
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

2.add this line android/setting.gradle
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android'):